# Is it possible to have nested divs in content fields on a view?

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to create a view that displays certain content fields inside a div that are contained by other content fields.

For example. I am displaying an image, a title, a body, and a posted date.

I'd like to do something like this

```
<div class="a">
   <img src="image.jpg">
   <div class="title">
      Title
   </div>
   <div class="text">
      <div id="postdate">
         1/1/1999
      </div>
      <div id="body">
         body text
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just **exclude from display** all your fields.

[image: Exclude from display]

Then, at the end, **create a Global text area**, where you can use tokens from your excluded fields.

[image: Global text area]

Answer (score 1):

exclude all the fields from display except the last field and rewrite the output of that field to apply the structure you need using tokens of the previous field.